# Rendered image in header/footer itext by using html header footer

Tags: java, itext, html-to-pdf

I am trying to add the html header and footer in my PDF. When I am adding text it is working fine, but when I am trying to give `<img>`, it is not able to render the image in the header of a  PDF document. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

```
package com.mrcooper.bulkextract.BulkExtractAutomation;

import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementList;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;

import java.io.IOException;


public class test  extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    protected ElementList header;
    protected ElementList footer;

    public static final String HEADER =
            " <img id=\"_x0000_i1027\" src=\"https://apolloimage.blob.core.windows.net/images/cooper-logo-cyan.png\" alt=\"Nationstar Mortgage logo\" width=\"199\" height=\"92\"><br>\n" +
                    "    <span style=\"color: #95bac9;font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px;margin-left:10px\">8950 Cypress Waters Blvd.</span><br>\n" +
                    "    <span style=\"color: #95bac9;font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px;margin-left:10px\">Dallas, TX 75019</span>";
    public static final String FOOTER =
            "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\"><tr><td>Footer</td><td align=\"right\">Some title</td></tr></table>";

    public test() throws IOException {
        header = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(HEADER, null);
        footer = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(FOOTER, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        try {
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
            ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(36, 832, 559, 810));
            for (Element e : header) {
                ct.addElement(e);
            }
            ct.go();
            ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(36, 10, 559, 32));
            for (Element e : footer) {
                ct.addElement(e);
            }
            ct.go();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your header area is 22 units high (810..832). The image has a height of 92 (`height=\"92\"`). It simply does not fit.

Comment: @Brian can we increase this height, do we have any attributes to customize the height and width of header and footer.

Comment: @mkl do you have any suggestion for the above question.

Comment: How about enlarging the rectangle parameter so the image may fit?